# issue saveWine using backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I got this code from https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-cellar. When I try to add new model to database using slim.php, it is showing "Error An error occurred while trying to add this item". But when I am trying to fetch, update, delete its working good. Why it is showing error only on adding ?

bootstrap/js/views/winedetails.js

```
window.WineView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        "click .save"   : "beforeSave",
        "click .delete" : "deleteWine"

    },

    beforeSave: function () {
        var self = this;
        var check = this.model.validateAll();
        if (check.isValid === false) {
            utils.displayValidationErrors(check.messages);
            return false;
        }

        // Upload picture file if a new file was dropped in the drop area
        if (this.pictureFile) {
            this.model.set("picture", this.pictureFile.name);
            utils.uploadFile(this.pictureFile,
                function () {
                    self.saveWine();
                }
            );
        } else {
            this.saveWine();
        }
        return false;
    },

    saveWine: function () {
        var self = this;
        this.model.save(null, {
            success: function (model) {
                self.render();
                app.navigate('wines/' + model.id, false);
                utils.showAlert('Success!', 'Wine saved successfully', 'alert-success');
            },
            error: function () {
                utils.showAlert('Error', 'An error occurred while trying to add this item', 'alert-error');
            }
        });
    },

    deleteWine: function () {
        this.model.destroy({
            success: function () {
                alert('Wine deleted successfully');
                window.history.back();
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

});
```

thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to see what error response your server is sending back.  You can use Firebug/Firefox, Chrome, etc. to see what the server's response was to your add request.  Alternatively, if you can `console.log` or `alert` the URL (say from inside Backbone) you could then simply browse to it normally.  Either way, once you see what your server is unhappy about you should be able to solve your issue.